# Add skype's smile as a bullet point on li tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this odd request from the client, to add a smile emoticon from Skype as a `list-style-type`. The problem is that he wants that emoticon with the animation too, because I thought of using font-awesome to add the emoticon.

Do you have any idea if it's possible to insert an emoticon with animation on the the last child of a list?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the last element of the `<li>`"? As it stands your question is not very clear.

Comment: it should be like this: li:last-child, but I can do this part.

Comment: If that's what you meant, then the way you phrased your question was a bit misleading - I edited it to make it more clear, and updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/w4392m6t/
Odd request (actually, so 90s:)), however - you need it on last li, right?

```
  ul {
        list-style-type:none;
    }
    ul li {
        position:relative;
        line-height:30px;
    }

    ul li:last-child:before {
        content:' ';
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
    background-image:url('https://az545065.vo.msecnd.net/skype-faq-media/faq_content/skype/screenshots/fa12330/emoticons/smile_80_anim_gif.gif');
        margin-left:-35px;
        background-size:30px 30px;

    }
```

EDIT: If you actually need image on all li tags, use   `list-style-image: url(your url)`: http://jsfiddle.net/w4392m6t/3/, before text, instead bullet.

Or, simple, use gif, as background image for li, and adjust position...

Comment: Perfect Man, that's what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Np, glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by styling the `::after` pseudoelement with a background image.

Here is a **live demo**:

```css
.list {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.list > li:last-child::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/I9ldaCx.png");
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Circle type</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually, i am not sure what OP means by "on the the last element of the <li>", too... Should all li's have smiley, or....

Comment: @nevermind Yeah, hmm... I guess you could interpret it in a few different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can mimic the smiling with special draw smile image from Skype in GIF type. You need to set `list-style-type: none` to hide all marks near `li`, and then simply add image before your text. For example:

```css
.list {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.list img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li><img src="http://www.robotspacebrain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/David-Szakaly-2.gif">Circle type</li>
  <li><img src="http://www.robotspacebrain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/David-Szakaly-2.gif">Tea</li>
  <li><img src="http://www.robotspacebrain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/David-Szakaly-2.gif">Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```